# Javafx GridPane child alignment

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, alignment, gridpane

I'd first like to say that I won't include any of my code, since the relevant code is widespread along many functions and files. I'm only asking to see if I did something blatantly wrong, otherwise I won't tire you with endless lines of code.

I'm trying to write a game of sorts using Java and JavaFX. I have created multiple `GridPane` objects containing different graphics (all placeholders for now), all stacked on a `StackPane`. One `GridPane` contains shadow objects, which are black squares on a low opacity, laid over the actual environment. A function determines whether a square should be shaded or not and then adds an instance of the black square on that location of the `GridPane`.

While everything is working fine, as you can see in the following images, the `GridPane` splits itself into areas.
It seems that every 25 squares vertically or horizontally, the `GridPane` adds a blank pixel line, offsetting everything else to the side, below, or both.

I've checked that all paddings are 0, and since the shadow images are added by integer values, I can't fathom why this is happening. Any ideas?

(As a very short snippet of code, this function adds the shadow squares)

```
shadowGrid.getChildren().clear();
for (int j=0;j<MAPYSIZE;j++){
    for (int i=0;i<MAPXSIZE;i++){
        if (isShaded(i,j)){
            ImageView shadow=new ImageView(shadowBlock);
            shadow.setOpacity(0.5);
            shadowGrid.add(shadow,i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: shadow error1]

[image: shadow error2],

Comment: Not really related to the problem, but if you use the same image file for different `ImageView`s you should load the data to a single `Image` instance and use it as data for the `ImageView`s. (However in this case `Rectangle`s would suffice too.)

Comment: It seems that the shadow grid is cut if it envelops a certain percentage of the screen. I still cannot fathom why this is happening. Any help, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

This might be long overdue, but I found the solution (because I had the same problem).

Namely, you need to call:

```
GridPane.setHalignment(objectYouWantToCenter, HPos.CENTER);
```

Before you add it into your shadowGrid. Note that this is not called on shadowGrid, but on the object GridPane.